# SSRS - Connecting dots on scatter plot graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to plot 2 scatter plot graphs on one report using SSRS2008. One should be a regular scatter plot (disconnected dots), but another one should connect the dots into a line, or a curve.

What properties need to be set and how?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set this up as a line chart, as normal.

For the values that are not to be connected:

- select the Data tab in the Chart Properties dialog, click on the relevant **Values:** item and click the **Edit...** button;
- on the Appearance tab of the Edit Chart Value dialog, check the **Show markers** option and select the desired marker type and size;
- then click the **Series Style...** button and set the Border and Line tab **Style:** value to be **none**.